# How to return generic type in a method interface

Tags: java

How to define a generic return type for an interface, so that it's implementing class can have a return type of its own?

```
public interface A {
    public <T> T doSomething();     
}


public class ImplA implements A {
    public SomethingElseA doSomething() {
        return obj.doSomething();
    }
}

public class ImplB implements A {
    public SomethingElseB doSomething() {
        return obj.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: `do` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy ok in what sense? It still won't compile.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy remove the brackets around `T` and specify that `T` is a type parameter for the interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something as follows.

```
interface A<T> {

  T doSomething();
}

class ImplA implements A<SomethingElseA> {

  public SomethingElseA doSomething() {
    ...
  }
}

class ImplB implements A<SomethingElseB> {

  public SomethingElseB doSomething() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean like this? I changed do() to foo() as do is a reserved word...

```
public interface A<T> {
    public T foo();      
}

public class ImplA implements A<SomethingElseA> {
    @Override
    public SomethingElseA foo() {
        return obj.doSomething();
    }
}

public class ImplB implements A<SomethingElseB> {
    @Override
    public SomethingElseB foo() {
        return obj.doSomething();
    }
}
```